# make object move to the mouse clicked position 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

This is the code for 3D in unity. I changed this to the 2D form, but the object does not move in the 2D world. The writer said it will be okay if I change the word from 3D to 2D, but I seem to be missing something.

```
private bool flag = false;
private Vector2 endPoint;
public float duration = 50.0f;
private float yAxis;

void Start()
{
    yAxis = gameObject.transform.position.y;
}

void Update()
{

    if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray;
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            flag = true;
            endPoint = hit.point;
            endPoint.y = yAxis;
            Debug.Log(endPoint);
        }

    }

    if (flag && !Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude))
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint, 1 / (duration * (Vector2.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint))));
    }

    else if (flag && Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude))
    {
        flag = false;
        Debug.Log("I am here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `flag` ever set to true?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Yes, look inside `if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))`

Comment: I meant if the code actually reaches this instruction while debugging. =)     He might not get a Raycast hit.

Comment: Ahh ok. I though you meant he's not setting it to true anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this code is working properly and all you want to do is make it work in 2D

[`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) should be [`RaycastHit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html)

[`Ray`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) should be [`Ray2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray2D.html).

[`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) should be [`Physics.Raycast2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html)

All you do is add `2D` to the end of those API then changing all your colliders to `colliders 2D` in the Editor. For example, `Box Collider` should be replaced with `Box Collider 2D`.

Replace:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray;
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    flag = true;
    endPoint = hit.point;
    endPoint.y = yAxis;
    Debug.Log(endPoint);
}
```

with

```
Vector2 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, Vector2.zero);
if (hit)
{
    flag = true;
    endPoint = hit.point;
    endPoint.y = yAxis;
    Debug.Log(endPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could be wrong here:

#### 1) You might not get a `Raycast` hit

[Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) needs *3D* Colliders in the scene. If you don't have them you can't get a hit and thus the movement part of the code is never activated.

#### 2) You might be mixing 2D and 3D

If you are on a purely 2D setup you will have to use `Physics2D` instead of `Physics`. So it will be [Physics2D.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).
This will also require you to use 2D Colliders.    One example is the [PolygonCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html)

Basically: If the class doesn't end with 2D it will not work with Physics2D.